# How to set a toggle button and text view in horizontal linear layout and scroll view for the same?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I have this xml with me ,I want to set  textview's for each toggle button and i want to set the textview and button together in a scroll view ? I have tried many code but i cud'nt set one text view and button horizontally and could'nt set the scroll view for the same ?Can anybody help me?

```
   <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="50sp">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ToggleButton



            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"

            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:textOn="ON"
            android:textOff="OFF"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

           />
        <ToggleButton

            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"

            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:textOn="00:30" 
            android:textOff="00:30"

            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:textOn="1:00" 
            android:textOff="1:00"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
           />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOff="1:30"
            android:textOn="1:30" 
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton5"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textOff="2:00"
            android:textOn="2:00" 
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            />


        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton6"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


            android:textOff="2:30"
            android:textOn="2:30" 
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton7"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:textOff="3:00"
            android:textOn="3:00" 
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
         />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton8"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


            android:textOff="3:30"
            android:textOn="3:30" 
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Sample layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.cozyne.toglebtn.MainActivity" >


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llTopBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="#00ff00"
    android:dividerPadding="22dip"
    android:showDividers="middle"
   >

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="75dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
      android:text="12:00 AM" />



<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="62dp"
       android:text="asdf" />


 </LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/llTopBar2"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/llTopBar"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:divider="#00ff00"
  android:dividerPadding="22dip"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:showDividers="middle" >







<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="75dp"
  android:layout_height="44dp"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/llTopBar"
  android:layout_below="@+id/llTopBar"
  android:text="12:30 AM" />


 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="62dp"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toggleButton1"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
  android:text="asdf" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Updated file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.cozyne.toglebtn.MainActivity" >
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llTopBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:divider="#00ff00"
    android:dividerPadding="22dip"
    android:showDividers="middle"
   >
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="75dp"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     android:text="12:00 AM" />
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="62dp"
       android:text="12:00" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/llTopBar2"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:divider="#00ff00"
  android:dividerPadding="22dip"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:showDividers="middle" >
 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="75dp"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      android:text="12:30 AM" />
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="62dp"
  android:text="12:30" />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/llTopBar3"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"


android:divider="#00ff00"
  android:dividerPadding="22dip"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:showDividers="middle" >
   <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_width="75dp"
  android:layout_height="44dp"
  android:text="1:00 AM" />


 <Button
  android:id="@+id/button3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="62dp"
  android:text="1:00" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: horizontal layout and vertical scrollview??

Comment: @Apurva :yes i want to set one text view and a button horizontally and also want to set scroll view for all buttons and textviews vertically.Can u help me?

Comment: Each needs to be within its own `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` instead of within one `ScrollView` if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, change this code:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"

        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

       />
```

into this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ScrollView requires to have only one child (which in your case is LinearLayout) but remember that you can nest layouts inside each others.

Comment: :-Thanx ,how to add more buttons and textviews vertically?? can i use another linear layout ??plz check the edit in ma question

Comment: Just copy the code above and paste it how many times you like it

Comment: Thanx, now one textview and button is on the top of another button and textview how can i align correctly??

Comment: @ rwojcik : Can u help me

Comment: Use linear layout with vertical orientation instead od relative layout

Comment: That is ok.But it does not show the buttons,only showing textviews...Can u check my updated file?i tried ,bt i don't knw what is the actual problem.Can u help me plz?